# JavaFX dynamycly add labels to pane, defined in fxml file

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, borderpane

I have the BorderPane in my fxml file. And I need to add labels to its center from the code in my controller class. As I understood I have to do it in `initialize()` method, but I didn't find out how to realize this.

**P.S.** I don't want to add them statically in fxml file, because their amount is different every time, it could 5 or could be 20. In that case I'd have to add their maximum amount and make them invisible. But I don't think it would be the best decision.

Comment: You might have to do it without fxml, it would be far easier. With fxml, it is not impossible (since I do not know what scenario you have), but you can try adding them to a flexible collection like an ArrayList (add however many labels you want to list and then iterate through array list adding whatever labels are present in it). Ofcourse, there might be better ways to do it, this is the one that strikes my mind at first go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your controller to your FXML and then created an initialize method that will be called.  You will need to annotate it with the @FXML annotation.

You also need to wire your border pane with the @FXML annotation. Here I assume it myBorderPane.

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    //Create the label
    Label myLabel = new Label("Will go in the Center Pane"); 
    myBorderPane.setCenter(myLabel);
}
```

Obviously this just hard codes one label into your pane.  You likely would need to create some logic around here to generate what you need.  You will also need to take care of layout, etc.

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: But man, I've already tried such variant and got nothing
There is my code:
`
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    BorderPane pane;
    
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        pane.setCenter(new Label("XYZ"));
    }
}
`

Comment: If you have tried code and it doesn't work, you need to put that in your question. Show just enough code (FXML, controller, and main class) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found my mistake - I didn't add Controller as a parametr of pane to fxml file. Now everything works fine.